# Docker-compose push images built from node alpine and mysql

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

## Preliminary Info

I have a docker-compose file that describes two services, one built from a dockerhub mysql image and the other built from a dockerhub node alpine image. The `docker-compose.yml` is as follows:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  client:
      image: node:alpine
      command: sh -c "cd server && yarn install && cd .. && yarn install && yarn start"
      ports:
        - "3000:3000"
      working_dir: /portal
      volumes: 
        - ./:/portal
      environment:
        MYSQL_HOST: mysql
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
        MYSQL_DB: files
  mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7
      volumes:
          - yaml-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
        MYSQL_DATABASE: files
    
volumes:
  yaml-mysql-data:
```

## Current Understanding

**I'm trying to deploy my app using kubernetes**, but a kubernetes .yml file requires that I provide a path to my container images on dockerhub. However, I don't have them on dockerhub. I'm not sure how to push my images as they are built from the mysql and node images that I pull.

I know that `docker-compose push` can be used, however it's for locally built images; whereas I'm pulling images from dockerhub and am providing specific instructions in my `docker-compose.yml` when spinning them up.

## Question

How can I push these images including the commands that should be run; e.g. `command: sh -c "cd server && yarn install && cd .. && yarn install && yarn start"`? (which is on line 5 of `docker-compose.yml` above)

Thanks

Comment: Hello. Adding to the part of "Current understanding":  You can use the private registries with Kubernetes. Please take a look here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/ . You can also use the images locally by specifying `Imagepullpolicy`: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic that you put in the docker-compose.yml actually belongs with a Dockerfile. So create a Dockerfile for your nodejs applications (there are plenty of examples for this).

Then in your docker-compose.yml you build your own image that you can then push to a registry.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  client:
      image: your_registry/your_name:some_tag
      build: .
      ports: ...
      environment: ....
```

Comment: Thanks I ended up using Dockerfiles instead. Was pretty simple from that point onward